# Control vs Experimental subjects

Tags: self-study, case-control-study

I wonder if I am reasoning correctly here? I feel that I might be missing something important.

[image]

Comment: If my answer makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is c. As your sample size grows, your test will be powerful enough that it will reject any small difference.

For example, if you have two very large samples and their means are 1000 and 1001. Your test may reject the null hypothesis, but that doesn't mean anything (practically meaningless).

Comment: FDA's gold standard is the randomized controlled experiment.  Although answer c) is something to be concerned about I don't think it is the only possible answer.  Couldn't the result be practically significant as well as statistically significant? Also suppose you don't randomize then  there can be differences between groups that don't relate to the treatment and hence any size effect may be misunderstood.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I think I understand your concerns. But, this question is obviously testing basic statistical understanding, we're not talking something like phd level.

Comment: I don't think my comment requires a PhD to understand it and I don't think we should try to read the OPs mind or guess at his education level.